# Deployment TypeScript files TFS and Octopus Deploy

Tags: typescript, octopus-deploy

We are using TFS 2018 as our CI tool and Octopus Deploy as our CD tool for our ASP.NET MVC5 applications. 
What is the best practice to compile the Type Script files in TFS and deploy the transpiled Javascript files including the Node_modules files to the web server?

We use Octopack to packages the MVC5 files into a pkg-package for Octopus Deploy.

We have trouble packaging the generated Javascript files at this Octopus package. And there is no node_modules map at the web server after deploying the newest version of our application. Can anyone help us to tackle this problem?

Comment: Install your node files *before* creating the package, and add the transpiled JS files to the package.  The octopus package is supposed to be completely ready for deployment.

Answer (score -1):

After several hours I solved this issue by adding a Powershell script a Custom Deployment script in the Post-Deployment field in Octopus Deploy.

The script contain this code: $installDirectory = $OctopusParameters[‘Octopus.Action.Package.CustomInstallationDirectory’]
cd $installDirectory
npm install --silent